# SugarCRM: Putting a image data type in 'Cases' module

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm

I use SugarCRM CE. I'm trying to create an image data type on the Cases module. The purpose of this is so that the employees of my company can attach images that can better explain the cases that they submit. However, I seem to have a hard time implementing this.

I tried to follow the guide at: https://www.atcoresystems.com/blog/adding-a-photo-to-a-contact-record

This apparently does not work for me as when I navigate to the detail view and the edit view of the record, it displays a mess of code instead of the expected output.

On my own, I also tried creating a custom field trying to emulate the 'file' data type of the "Documents" module and using a javascript to display it on the Detail View but no luck at all.
I am able to display something similar to the browse file on the "Documents" Edit View but as soon as I save it, it doesn't show.

Also to include in my worries, even after I successfully use it to accept files and display them, how do I filter them to accept only image files?

Please help!!!

Comment: You should try this photo module. It does exactly what you're wanting: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/photo

Comment: Thanks Chad. I've looked at some of these addons beforehand and was considering it, but the budget from my company is another matter. Basically, we have to develop everything from the ground-up or find open-source or free alternatives to it. I figure it's implementable but I also know it may be difficult.

Comment: gotcha, I see that a lot. It is an open sourced module once you purchase it. I'm curious how much time has been spent with you going down this path, but you're still without a solution, compared to if you just purchased the module to begin with. We've found the "buy" side of the buy vs. build argument usually wins in the SugarCRM world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this question last Friday and I thought I'd share what worked for me. I revisited https://www.atcoresystems.com/blog/adding-a-photo-to-a-contact-record and decided to give it another shot. However, on Section 4.2, I changed this:

```
elseif($_FILES[$this->field_name]['size']
```

to this:

```
 elseif($_FILES[$field_name]['size']
```

I cleared the cache but mostly what really grounded me was that even after doing so, I still got the same results. So to solve this, I modified my search query and picked other random records to edit. Problem solved!